# derivative of a function at a point does not exist

Tags: calculus

Given the set of all real number $\mathbb R$ and a real function $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow  \mathbb R =\begin{cases}x^n&\textrm{if } x\geq0 \\0 &\textrm{if } x=0)\end{cases}$  
 Determine all the natural number $n$ so that $\frac{dg(0)}{dx}$ does not exist. 
 
 I read in a literature that "If $f$ is not continuous at $a$, then $f'(a)$ does not exist." 
 Since $g=\begin{cases}x^n& \textrm{if }x\geq0 \\0 &{\textrm{if } x=0}\end{cases}$, the first derivative is $\frac{dg(x)}{dx}=\begin{cases}nx^{n-1}&\textrm{if } x\geq0 \\0 &{\textrm{if }x=0}\end{cases}$ 

 I try to find all natural number n so that $g(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$ so that $\frac{dg(0)}{dx}$ does not exist.

 I also read that $f$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if 

 1. $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)$ exists,

 2. $f(c)$ exists, and

 3. $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=f(c)$.

 I have checked for $g(x)$

 1. $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x^n=0  \forall n \in \mathbb N$

 2. $g(0)=0$

 3. $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=g(0)=0$.

 Thus, $g(x)$ is continuous at $0 \forall n \in \mathbb N$

 
 This makes me conclude that there is no natural number $n$ so that $\frac{dg(0)}{dx}$ does not exist. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is true that the derivative does not exist when the function is not continuous. But that doesn't mean that the _only_ way for a function not to have a derivative is if it is discontinuous. For example $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous everywhere but has no derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: That case distinction in $g$ and $g'$ is confusing me. Is $<0$ meant?

Comment: Do you include $0$ in the natural numbers?

Comment: @Henning, I see. Thank you for giving me the counterexample, Henning Makholm

Comment: @mvw, the function is only given for $x \geq 0$, I think it is not defined for $x<0$. And no, I do not include $0$ in natural numbers as $\mathbb N = {1,2,3,...}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=1$ then $$\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow0}\frac{g\left(\epsilon\right)-g\left(0\right)}{\epsilon}=1\neq0=\lim_{\epsilon\uparrow0}\frac{g\left(\epsilon\right)-g\left(0\right)}{\epsilon}$$
This means that $$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{g\left(\epsilon\right)-g\left(0\right)}{\epsilon}$$
is not defined.

If $n>1$ then $$\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow0}\frac{g\left(\epsilon\right)-g\left(0\right)}{\epsilon}=0=\lim_{\epsilon\uparrow0}\frac{g\left(\epsilon\right)-g\left(0\right)}{\epsilon}$$
Wich means that $$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{g\left(\epsilon\right)-g\left(0\right)}{\epsilon}$$
is defined and equals $0$.

---

If a function is not continuous at some $a$ then it is not differentiable at $a$. In general the converse of this is not true (see comment of Henning for a counterexample).

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I do not understand what is $\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow0}\frac{g\left(\epsilon\right)-g\left(0\right)}{\epsilon}$ and $\lim_{\epsilon\uparrow0}\frac{g\left(\epsilon\right)-g\left(0\right)}{\epsilon}$. Are they alike left-hand limit and right-hand limit?

Comment: Yes. The limit itself exists if and only if left-hand limit and right-hand limit both exist and are equal.

Comment: Is $\lim_{\epsilon\uparrow0}\frac{g\left(\epsilon\right)-g\left(0\right)}{\epsilon}$ the right-hand limit? If yes, Could you explain why the left-hand limit is 1? I think the function $g$ is only defined for $x \geq 0$, we doesn't know $g(x)$ for $x<0$.

Comment: The limit you mention is the left-hand limit. The thing is that you start with a function $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$. That suggests that $g(x)$ is defined for *any* $x\in\mathbb R$. However, then comes the prescription that only gives values $g(x)$ for nonnegative $x$. That is peculiar: $g$ is *defined* for negative $x$ but not *prescribed*. Something is probably wrong here. If you don't know $g(x)$ for negative values of $x$ then it is impossible to say anything sensible about (the existence of) its derivative in $0$. In my answer I treated the case where $g(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$.

Comment: BTW, to avoid confusion: do not use double prescriptions. You should
not split up in $x\geq0$ and $x=0$. The first case includes the
second case.

Comment: I see. So the function $g$ should be defined for all real numbers ($x<0,x=0,x>0$) first before it can be solved, right? Sadly, the question I have from random source doesn't define $g$ for $x<0$, thus it can't be solved. Assuming that $g(x)=x^n$ for $x>0$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$, your answer of my question is $n=1$, right?

Comment: In general $g'\left(a\right)$ can only exist if $g$ is defined on
an open set that contains $a$, or equivalently if some $\epsilon>0$
exists s.t. $g$ is defined on the interval $\left(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon\right)$.
These conditions are necessary (not sufficient). In the case that you describe in your comment the answer of your question is indeed $n=1$.